# If I have a Bernoulli(x) random variable that counts poisson(y) if it returns successful and counts poisson(z) if it fails, what is the variance?

Tags: probability, distributions, poisson-distribution, bernoulli-distribution

I'm attempting to calculate the variance of this problem in a way that I can apply to future, similar problems.

Comment: Apply the [tower property of variance](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=tower+variance+condition*).

Answer (score 3):

Suppose we denote your random variable of interest as $A$ and use another random variable $B$ as your conditioning random variable.  We can write your model as:

$$A|B \sim \text{Pois}(z+(y-z)B)
\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad 
B \sim \text{Bern}(x).$$

Using the [law of total variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_variance), the variance of the random variable of interest is:

$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{V}(A) 
&= \mathbb{E}(\mathbb{V}(A|B)) + \mathbb{V}(\mathbb{E}(A|B)) \\[6pt]
&= \mathbb{E}(z+(y-z)B) + \mathbb{V}(z+(y-z)B) \\[6pt]
&= (z+(y-z)x) + (y-z)^2 x(1-x) \\[6pt]
&= z+(y-z)x + (y-z)^2 x(1-x) \\[6pt]
&= z + (y-z)(1 + y-z)x - (y-z)^2 x^2. \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$